# Disable treesitter highlighting for neovim 0.9

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

I do not use syntax highlighting, except for a few elements like errors, matched parentheses, search results, and diffs. Yesterday I updated NeoVim installation to v0.9.0 and now I see colors in for statements, strings, html tags, etc. Based on the release notes I assume this was caused by "treesitter".

Is there a way to revert back to my previous setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `vim.treesitter.stop` in [Neovim docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/treesitter.html). It is specific to buffers, but I think you can expand it.
The nuclear option I think would be using th module `vim.treesitter.highlighter` and
`TSHighlighter:destroy({self})`. I suggest you to look at the doc I linked above.

Comment: Thanks for the doc. I read it and seems like tree-sitter highlight groups are linked to Vims highlight groups so this isn't the issue. I tracked the issue down to  init.vim not respecting my colorscheme. Colors get back to normal if after starting neovim I manually call `:colors` again.